# Beamer: use helvetica only in \textsc

Tags: small-caps, sans-serif, helvetica

I am using beamer and I would like to use `\textsc` but with Helvetica. Adding

```
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
```

to the preamble does the job. Problem is, this changes too all the text of the slides to Helvetica, since I am using

```
\usefonttheme{default}
```

to get sans serif on my slides (by default, it is Computer Modern Sans Serif). I want to use Computer Modern Sans Serif in the rest of the slides, not Helvetica. I have looked through TSE questions and I have found nothing related. How can I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Okey, I just figured it out.

There is no need at all to load the `helvet` package; instead, we can use

```
\textsc{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
    Your Text Goes Here
}
```

to get the desired result.

Actually, by default, Helvetica on LaTeX can be too big in comparison with other fonts. To turn Helvetica into a "normal size" while avoiding my original problem, we can add

```
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{cmss}
```

to the preamble. The first line reescales Helvetica to 92% of its default size. The second line resets the default sans serif font to Computer Modern Sans Serif.